# Not getting Function value in variable in officejs

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins, add-in, outlook-web-addins, custom-properties

I am using **custom property** in the outlook add-in. I had saved some custom property. Now, I'm **retrieving** it in a local variable. While I'm retrieving the custom property at that time it's **showing undefined**. I had pasted the code. I want to store custom property in some variable that's why I tried to store it in the **test** variable. But it's not going to store the values in the test varible. My functions get executed after **printing console**. I didn't know where I had done a mistake.

can anyone guide me on this problem?

[image: Undefined image]

```
const mailbox = Office.context.mailbox.item;
const test = mailbox.loadCustomPropertiesAsync(function (result) {
  const customProps = result.value;
  const property = customProps.get("CustomMeeting");
  return property;
})

console.log('Custom property', test)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code custom property is getting printed before the async call finishes. To ensure that call has completed, you can do the following:

```js
let cp;
const mailbox = Office.context.mailbox.item;
mailbox.loadCustomPropertiesAsync(lcpCallback);
function lcpCallback(result) {
if (result.status != Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
  cp = result.value;
  console.log('Custom property:'+ JSON.stringify(cp));
}}
```